# Disable additional criteria only in some entity relations

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, soft-delete

I am making an application based on JPA/EclipseLink, I implemented a soft delete functionality using @AdditionalCriteria in the root class of the hierarchy of entities (all entities inherit from this).

My problem is that now, I need to create a special entity that contains multiple relationships with other entities; and I need recover all relationed entities, including soft deleted ones. It is possible disabled @AdditionalCriteria only in the relations of this special entity with EclipseLink? If not, what is the best option to do this? My code looks like the following:

```
////Example of my top entity class (all others inherit from this)
@AdditionalCriteria("this.deleted = false")
public abstract class TopHierarchyClass {
  ···
  @Column(name = "deleted")
  protected boolean deleted = false;
  ···
}

//Example of entity that needs recover all relationed entities including soft deleted
@Entity
@Table(name = "special_entities")
public class SpecialEntity extends EntityBase {
  ···
  @JoinColumn(name = "iditem", referencedColumnName = "id")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Item item;
  ···
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Item extends EntityBase {
  ···
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new entity for the same table without the `@AdditionalCriteria`. This way you can retrieve all records from that table without applying the additional filter.

For example:

```
public interface Person {
    Long getId();
    void setId(Long id);
    Date getDeletedAt();
    void setDeletedAt(Date deletedAt);
}

@MappedSupperclass
public class PersonEntity implements Person {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private Date deletedAt;

    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    public Date getDeletedAt() { return deletedAt; }
    public void setDeletedAt(Date deletedAt) { this.deletedAt = deletedAt; }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
@AdditionalCriteria("this.deletedAt is null")
public class ActivePersonEntity extends PersonEntity {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
public class RawPersonEntity extends PersonEntity {
}

public class PeopleRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<Person> all() {
       return all(false);
    }

    public List<Person> all(boolean includeSoftDeleted) {
       if (!includeSoftDeleted) {
           return em.createQuery("select p from ActivePersonEntity p", ActivePersonEntity.class).getResultList();
       } else {
           return em.createQuery("select p from RawPersonEntity p", RawPersonEntity.class).getResultList();
       }
    }
}
```

Also, if your `@AdditionalCriteria` is in a super class, you may override it by declaring a new empty `@AdditionalCriteria` in a sub class:

> You can define additional criteria on entities or mapped superclass.
>   When specified at the mapped superclass level, the additional criteria
>   definition applies to all inheriting entities, unless those entities
>   define their own additional criteria, in which case those defined for
>   the mapped superclass are ignored.

[@AdditionalCriteria doc](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_additionalcriteria.htm)